# variadic macro to generate a vector of strings from a collection of unknown parameters

Tags: c++, macros, string-formatting, variadic

Currently I am working on a function similar to the `String.Format(...)` function from C#, just in C++. ([String.Format(...)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx))

But that's not my problem. The function works fine but problematic is that it takes a `vector<string>` as parameter and if I want to use an integer as parameter, I must write code like this:

```cpp
// function prototype, the function body is not relevant here
string format(string str, vector<string> variables);

// ... some context
  // i could use to_string() here,
  // but imagine a complex type which only overrides the stream operator
  int a = 20; 
  stringstream ss;
  ss << a;
  string a_str = format("a has the value '{}'", { ss.str() });
```

**That's quite some boilerplate code!**

Thus I need a function which converts a collection of *unknown* data types into a `vector<string>`.

I tried a few things like this:

```
vector<string> vec_string(vector<void*> args) {
    vector <string> result;

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < args.size(); i++)
    {
        stringstream ss;

        // I can't dereference an object without knowing to pointer type. :(
        ss << *((int*)args[i]);

        result.push_back(ss.str());
    }

    return result;
}

// ... some context

int a = 10;
cout << format("some int: '{}'", vec_string({ (void*) &a }));
```

Which obviously only works for integer and is very uncomfortable. I feel like the only way to do this is a *variadic macro* but I got no idea how they work.

*[here](https://gist.github.com/SlimyDeath/36759d2420f2c18801152ef2d780e9f5) is a link to my `format(...)` method.
I am sorry about my spelling, but I tried my best correcting it.*

Comment: Lookup what you can do with `std::tuple`, `std::initializer_list` and `std::forward`.

Comment: Variadic macros are a bad idea here IMO, check out variadic templates for similar functionality within the C++ type system.

Comment: I am reading [this](https://www.murrayc.com/permalink/2015/12/05/modern-c-variadic-template-parameters-and-tuples/) right now, and it seems like the entire thing is a lot more complex than I thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done relatively easily with variadic templates:

```
template <class T>
auto toString(T&& t) {
    std::stringstream s;
    s << std::forward<T>(t);
    return s.str();
}

template <class... T>
auto toStringVector(T&&... args) {
    std::vector<std::string> res {toString(std::forward<T>(args))...};
    return res;
}
```

This will convert each parameter to `std::string` via a `stringstream` and then return an `std::vector<std::string>` containing said strings. ([Live example.](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/U1vdHILD8UE1z1Pq))

You can then use this straight forward as intended in the question, that is:

```
std::cout << format("some text", toStringVector(any, number, of, arguments,
                                      of, any, type));
```

If you are using Boost, you can skip the `toString` helper in favor of `boost::lexical_cast`:

```
template <class... T>
auto toStringVector(T&&... args) {
    std::vector<std::string> res { boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(std::forward<T>(args))...};
    return res;
}
```

The `lexical_cast` will most likely be faster on built-in types.

Comment: Ahh, you answered my question just 30 seconds, before I figured it out myself. (obviously your answer is better ...) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, no idea how I did that on the first try - without compiler errors, but here is how I did it:

```cpp
// function prototype, the function body is not relevant here
string format(string str, vector<string> variables);

template <class T>
vector<string> paramsToString(vector<string> vec, T last) {
    stringstream ss;
    ss << last;
    vec.push_back(ss.str());

    return vec;
}

template <class T, class ... REST>
vector<string> paramsToString(vector<string> vec, T next, REST ... rest) {
    stringstream ss;
    ss << next;
    vec.push_back(ss.str());

    return paramsToString(vec, rest...);
}

template <class ... ARGS>
vector<string> paramsToString(ARGS ... args) {
    return paramsToString(vector<string>(), args ...);
}

// ... some context

// ComplexType overrides the stream operator.
cout << format("an int: '{0}', and string: '{1}' and some other type: '{2}'", 
  paramsToString(10, "Hello World", ComplexType(10)));
```

And it works! Even with custom types. Amazing!

**Thank You guys for your help!**

Comment: Neat. You have some unnecessary copies though, see my answer on how to avoid those.